# Terraria multiplayer android vs pc

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I am trying to connect PC and mobile together. But mobile won't show on my PC. Is it really possible?

Comment: This would be great. I wonder if someone could make a proxy server that could act as a gateway between the two versions?

Answer (score -1):

They are different versions and are not cross compatible. And it won't be in the near future.